# Люди снимают шляпу/шляпы?

Tags: грамотная-речь, фразеология, единственное-множественное-число

Подскажите, пожалуйста, слово "шляпа" надо использовать во множественном или единственном числе?
**Перед этим человеком все большие и малые люди снимают шляпу** (или **шляпы**).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я вижу здесь два смысла и, соответственно, две возможности согласования.

Ситуация первая.
Люди действительно снимают шляпы (то есть совершают конкретное действие) — в знак почтения или уважения, в церкви, на похоронах, в парикмахерской.
Вот в этом случае, думаю, надо использовать множественное число:
*Перед этим человеком все большие и малые люди снимают* [свои] *шляпы.*

Загадка: перед кем все люди без исключения **снимают шляпы**? Отгадка: перед парикмахером.

*Все знали и уважали пана Здановского, и когда этот сухонький, сгорбленный старичок <...> выходил на новотаргский рынок, — **все снимали перед ним шляпы**...* (К. Тетмайер)

Ситуация вторая.
Выражение [**снимать шляпу**](https://phrase_dictionary.academic.ru/2415/%D0%A1%D0%9D%D0%98%D0%9C%D0%90%D0%A2%D0%AC_%D0%A8%D0%9B%D0%AF%D0%9F%D0%A3) используется как фразеологизм (то есть действие не производится) — по достоинству оценивать чьи-то заслуги, достижения, выражая свое почтение этому человеку (существительное ставится **обычно в ед. ч.**).

*Что сказать, штормит, но **мы** всегда **снимаем шляпу** перед этой напастью, и она отступает* (А. Медведев); *Перед ним давно уже **снимают шляпу все** диетологи мира*... (М. Жмакин [о кабачке]).

Answer (score 1):

*Снимать шляпу* — фразеологизм, и его не следует преобразовывать. Вот со «всеми большими и малыми» следует крепко поразмышлять.